# Are CORE_DIRECTIVES to add in controller's 'directives' array and how to use them correctly?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

According to Angular 2 docs; I am supposed to add

> import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';

and put **CORE_DIRECTIVES** in controller's **directives** array, in order to use ngFor etc.

However I can freely use those core directives even without that.

e.g.

> {{options}}

Same doubt for **DOM events** such as (click), etc.

Also, apparently one of the core directives is **ngClass** but I can freely use **class** (as in plain HTML) without any issue, including interpolation in class list.

**How is it supposed to work exactly?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

This doesn't apply to Angular2 final.
In Angular2 final every module where components or directives are used need to import a module that exports these components or directives.

See also [How to make directives and components available globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560817/how-to-make-directives-and-components-available-globally)

**original**

`CORE_DIRECTIVES` are provided by default since a few versions.

There is no need to import or provide them explicitly, except when you want to extend the list of directives that are provided by default

For example

```
provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES], multi: true})
```

to make `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` available globally by default as well.

- `PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES` provides `COMMON_DIRECTIVES` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9092ac79d49edee5e58cf26d890209766885753f/modules/angular2/src/platform/browser_common.ts#L82
- `COMMON_DIRECTIVES` provides `CORE_DIRECTIVES` and `FORM_DIRECTIVES` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d272f96e23f379e1b565435b3af010138e710ab9/modules/angular2/src/common/common_directives.ts#L49
- `CORE_DIRECTIVES` are listed at https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f4e6994634a9cf6c2c20aa8c2268233e2667edf8/modules/angular2/src/common/directives/core_directives.ts#L50
- `FORM_DIRECTIVES` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/60727c4d2ba1e4b0b9455c767d0ef152bcedc7c2/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/directives.ts#L67