# How to make directives and components available globally

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I wrote a custom directive that I use in my Angular 2 application to close content panels (some content holders in my template) in all the different components of my Angular 2 application. Since this code is quite the same for each component, I thought that I would make sense to write a directive that I could define once, and use in all components. This is what my directive looks like:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myCloseContentPanel]'
})

export class CloseContentPanelDirective {
    private el: HTMLElement;

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.el = el.nativeElement;
    }

    @HostListener('click') onMouseClick() {
        this.el.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Now I expected that I could import this directive once in a app.component parent component, and that I then could use this directive throughout all the child components. This sadly doesn't work, so I would have to import this directive in each component separately. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this behaviour simply not possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**update >=RC.5**

You have to import a module in whatever module you want to use components, directives or pipes of the imported module. There is no way around it.

What you can do is to create a module that exports several other modules (for instance, the `BrowserModule` that exports `CommonModule`.

```ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [CoolComponent, CoolDirective, CoolPipe],
  imports: [MySharedModule1, MySharedModule2],
  exports: [MySharedModule1, MySharedModule2, CoolComponent, CoolDirective, CoolPipe],
})
export class AllInOneModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [AllInOneModule]
})
class MyModule {}
```

This way you make everything exported by `AllInOneModule` available to `MyModule`.

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

**update <=RC.5**

```ts
bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [CloseContentPanelDirective], multi: true})]);
```

See comments below - even though per style guide `providers` in the root component should be favored over `boostrap()` this doesn't work:

**original**

<strike>On the root component add</strike>

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [CloseContentPanelDirective], multi: true})],
  templat: `...`
})
export component AppComponent {
}
```

`@Component()`, `@Directive()`, `@Pipe()` already include `@Injectable()`. No need to add it there as well.

Comment: Thanks! The answer works when I add this in the bootstrap file of my application, not when I add it in the root component. As I understand, adding it in the bootstrap file isn't best practice, do you have an idea what this could be?

Comment: Actually, I haven't tried it in `providers: [...]` of component myself yet. I posted the code this way because the style guide discourages using `bootstrap()`. You could try adding it to `directives: []` instead.

Comment: Directives and providers didn't work for me, bootstrap did. If you mention this in your answer I'll accept it!

Comment: Thanks for testing and your feedback! I updated the my answer. Just for your information. You could also add `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` like `[CloseContentPanelDirective, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]` to make them available globally. I show this just to get the idea how this works, you might not want to actually do this.

Comment: Any ideea how it can be done in the latest version of Angular2? Just declaring it in the main module doesnt seem to do the trick and the provide and PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES seem depricated.

Comment: You sure were fast! Thank you so much!

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is it still true for Angulr v2.4.x?

Comment: The part before **update** is still true. There is no way to provide directives or components globally, everything you want to use needs to be added to `imports: []` of the current module.