# Angular2: Make a directive available in the whole app

Tags: angular

I have defined a directive in Angular2 and I would like to make it available to all my components without having to do : `directives: [MyDir]` in every component.

I guess there should be a way as `*ngIf` by instance is available everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**update**

`PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES` are gone in 2.0.0 final.
See [How to make directives and components available globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560817/how-to-make-directives-and-components-available-globally)

**original**

in `bootstrap()` provide

```ts
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  // for global directives
  provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [MyDir], multi: true}),
  // for global pipes
  provide(PLATFORM_PIPES, {useValue: [RainbowizePipe], multi:true})
]);
```

Comment: Thanks sir, exactly what I needed. I have also found this : http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html which can be useful.